# Daterangepicker: Set minDate in second calendar depending on chosen date in a first cal

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have 2 calendar, the date needed and the good thru. I used jquery whenever the date needed changed then I have function named called GetGoodThru.

In my function this is where you get the value of the first calendar which is the date needed then I want to set my 2nd calendar minDate as my first calendar.

**View**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control dates" name="date_needed" id="date_needed"/>    
<input type="text" class="form-control dates" name="good_thru" id="good_thru"/>
```

**JS**

```
 function GetGoodThru()
    {
       var date_needed  = new Date($('#date_needed').val());
       //var terms           = parseInt($('#terms').val(), 10);
        if(!isNaN(date_needed.getTime())){
            date_needed.setDate(date_needed.getDate());
            date_needed.minDate(date_needed.getDate());
            $('#good_thru').val(date_needed.toInputFormat());
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Date");  
        }
    }
    $('div').on("blur", "input#date_needed",function(e){
         GetGoodThru();
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
    });
```

Question: How can I set as minDate for my 2nd calendar depends on the 1st calendar?